# SQL Beginner: Getting items from 2 tables (+grouping+ordering)

Tags: sql, virtuemart

[image]

I have an e-commerce website (using VirtueMart) and I sell products that consist child products. When a product is a parent, it doesn't have ParentID, while it's children refer to it. I know, not the best logic but I didn't create it.

My SQL is very basic and I believe I ask for something quite easy to achieve

- Select products that have children.
- Sort results by prices (ASC/DSC).

Comment: please tag your db

Comment: You need the [exists](http://www.w3resource.com/sql/special-operators/sql_exists.php) operator.

Comment: You are looking for [tag:recursive-queries] using a [tag:common-table-expression] (And you should **really** use `NULL` instead of zero to identify a row without a parent. Using `0` you can't have a proper foreign key constraint in your products table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This table design is subpar for a number of reasons.  First, it appears that the value 0 is being used to indicate lack of a parent (as there's no 0 ID for products).  Typically this will be a NULL value instead.

If it were a NULL value, the SQL statement to get everything without a parent would be as simple as this:

```
SELECT * FROM Products WHERE ParentID IS NULL
```

However, we can't do that.  If we make the assumption that 0 = no parent, we can do this:

```
SELECT * FROM Products WHERE ParentID = 0
```

However, that's a dangerous assumption to make.  Thus, the correct way to do this (given your schema above), would be to compare the two tables and ensure that the parentID exists as a ProductID:

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM Products AS a 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Products AS b WHERE a.ID = b.ParentID)
```

Next, to get the pricing, we have to join those two tables together on a common ID.  As the Prices table seems to reference a ProductID, we can use that like so:

```
SELECT p.ProductID, p.ProductName, pr.Price
FROM Products AS p INNER JOIN Prices AS pr ON p.ProductID = pr.ProductID
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Products AS b WHERE p.ID = b.ParentID)
ORDER BY pr.Price
```

That might be sufficient per the data you've shown, but usually that type of table structure indicates that it's possible to have more than one price associated with a product (we're unable to tell whether this is true based on the quick snapshot).

That should get you close... if you need something more, we'll need more detail.

Answer (score 2):

`SELECT * FROM Products INNER JOIN Prices ON Products.ProductID = Prices.ProductID ORDER BY Products.Price [ASC/DSC]`

Explanation:

`SELECT` - Select (Get/Retrieve)

`*` - ALL

`FROM Products` - Get them from a DB Table named "Products".

`INNER JOIN Prices` - Selects all rows from both tables as long as there is a match between the columns in both tables. Rather, JOIN DB Table "Products" with DB Table "Prices".

`ON` - Like `WHERE`, this defines which rows will be checked for matches.

`Products.ProductID = Prices.ProductID` - Your match criteria. Get the rows where "ProductID" exists in both DB Tables "Products" and "Prices".

`ORDER BY Products.Price [ASC/DSC]` - Sorting. Use `ASC` for Ascending, `DSC` for Descending.

Answer (score 1):

use the below script if you are using ssms.

```
SELECT pd.ProductId,ProductName,Price
FROM product pd
LEFT JOIN price pr ON pd.ProductId=pr.ProductID
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM  product pd1 WHERE pd.productID=pd1.ParentID)
ORDER BY pr.Price ASC
```

Note :neither of your parent product have price in price table. If  you want the sum of price of their child product use the below script.

```
SELECT pd.ProductId,pd.ProductName,SUM(ISNULL(pr.Price,0)) SUM_ChildPrice
FROM product pd
LEFT JOIN  product pd1 ON pd.productID=pd1.ParentID
LEFT JOIN price pr ON pd1.ProductId=pr.ProductID
GROUP BY  pd.ProductId,pd.ProductName
ORDER BY pr.Price ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use [self-join](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-self-joins.htm):

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM products parent 
JOIN products children ON parent.id = children.parent_id
JOIN prices ON prices.product_id = children.id
ORDER BY prices.price
```

Because we are using JOIN it will filter out all entries that don't have any children.

I haven't tested it, I hope it would work.